# How do I use TrSteelCkEditorBundle in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, bundle

I am new in the world of `sf2` and I am trying to learn it.
I installed `TrSteelCkEditorBundle` with composer and now I am trying to get the editor in a view.
My bundle is active in the `AppKernel`.

As a beginner my question is:
What do I have to do to make it works? 
I put this code and paste the value in the render

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('content', 'ckeditor', array(
            'transformers' => array(),
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

And in the twig view i have line 6:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

but i'm getting an error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: 
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() 
must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, 
instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form given, called in 
/Applications/mamp/htdocs/Sf2/app/cache/dev/twig/5c/eb/e10823d760716de7f56b39640e79.php 
on line 29 and defined in 
/Applications/mamp/htdocs/Sf2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRenderer.php
line 131") in amTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 6.
```

If someone had a clue to resolve that it'll help me a lot.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{{ form_widget(form) }}` doesn't work because your `$form` variable is the form itself. In order to get Twig to create the widgets for it, you have to send it to the Twig template with:

```
$form->createView()
```

Here is an example of when you return in your controllerAction:

```
return $this->render(
        'AcmeFooBundle:Acme:template.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView()) //Here you see the createView()
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that important detail. Now I'm having an error : `"Route" route_name" does not exist`. So I must  define the route somewhere, so the controller knows where to find the form.